# Distance metric on Stiefel manifold vs Grassmannian

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-algebras

Initially I was using a distance metric based on principle angles from [this](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/work/schubert.pdf) paper to calculate distances in the Grassmannian manifold. However, my project slightly changed and it seems like my manifold is now composed of ordered vectors. Hence I found that the Stiefel manifold might be more appropriate.

However, I don't know if distance metrics for the Grassmannian can still be used in my case. From [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/c8apiq/stiefel_manifold_and_geodesic/) it seems like I need a different distance metric for the Stiefel, but I'm not sure where to find any.

Comment: The Stiefel manifold $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of $k$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $SO(n)/SO(n-k)$. Using the bi-invariant Riemannian metric on both, there are Riemannian submersions $SO(n) \rightarrow V_k(\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow G(n,k)$. You might be able to figure out the distance function from this.

Comment: You might want to start by looking at $V_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $V_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$. If you figure these out, then you should be able to do the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distance function on the Grasmannian $d_G:Gr(n,k)\times Gr(n,k)\to\mathbb{R}$ won't suffice, in that we cannot define a distance function on the Stiefel manifold $d_S:V(n,k)\times V(n,k)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $d_S(E,F):=d_G(\operatorname{span}(E),\operatorname{span}(F))$. This is because there are distinct $k$-frames $E\neq F$ which span the same subspace, and defining $d_S$ in this manner would give $d_S(E,F)=0$.

Still, there are many possible distance functions on $V(n,k)$, and which to choose depends on the properties you want this distance to have. Since $V(n,k)$ embeds canonically into $\mathbb{R}^{nk}$, one could simply use Euclidean distances in $\mathbb{R}^{nk}$, or alternately use the geodesic distance from the Riemannian metric induced by this embedding.